# Minimization problem, constrained on the positive unit sphere

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I have the following problem:
$$ \arg\min_{\{x_i\}}\sum_{i,j}w_{i,j}\left\Vert x_{i}-c_{j}\right\Vert ^{2},\\
s.t. x_i^Tx_i=1\forall i,\quad x_i\succeq 0\forall i $$

where $x_i\in \mathbb R^K$, $i=1,...,M$ and $c_i\in \mathbb R^K$, $i=1,...,N$, are vectors, and $w_{i,j}$ is a scalar.

That is, I would like to find a set of suitable vectors $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^M$ that minimize the objective, constrained on the positive part of the unit sphere.
Appreciate any directions...

Comment: It's neither linear programming, nor convex...

Comment: Oops, you're right, I thought about a different problem when I wrote the title.

Comment: This problem is also separable. That is, you can solve for each $x_i$ separately.